# Adding shadow to UIView with UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibezierpath

I am creating a custom shape in draw rect method of UIView. It's an arrow and it's working, but I am having trouble adding the shadow. I've tried to add shadow to View itself and also layer but it doesn't work. Any help will be appreciated.

```
import UIKit

class ArrowView: UIView {

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        //Drawing Arrow
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        let edge:CGFloat = 20.0
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width - edge, y: 0.0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width , y: self.frame.height/2))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width - edge , y: self.frame.height))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.frame.height))
        path.close()

        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        layer.mask = mask

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not very helpful. Please elaborate what you mean.

Comment: @koen - means it's not showing the shadow. I thought it's clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can get Shadow

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class ArrowView: UIView {


    private lazy var arrowLayer : CALayer = {
        let layer = CALayer()
        layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        return layer
    }()


    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupView()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)

        setupView()


    }
    func setupView() {
        self.backgroundColor = .clear
        layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        layer.shadowOpacity = 1
        layer.shadowOffset = .zero
        layer.shadowRadius = 10


        layer.addSublayer(arrowLayer)
    }

    private func updatePath() {
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        let edge:CGFloat = 20.0
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.bounds.size.width - edge, y: 0.0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.bounds.size.width , y: self.bounds.size.height/2))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.bounds.size.width - edge , y: self.bounds.size.height))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.bounds.size.height))
        path.close()

        arrowLayer.frame = self.bounds

        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath

        arrowLayer.mask = mask
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        updatePath()
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: i hope it will help you :)

Comment: Awesome.  Can you please explain it a little? I really want to understand the logic.

Comment: if you mask a layer ... you cant give it shadow .... so i mask some other layer .. and give shadow to main layer ... and please avoid using draw method ....

Comment: thanks but there is a problem with your solution. When I was masking the main Layer I was able to add subviews inside the main UIView. Now if I add a subView it shows up in the whole view even outside of the UIBezierPath.